# Updating row on mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update a row on a table and it is not updating.
This is my html and php code :

```
<?php
if ($_GET) {
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['id']);
        echo $id;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='{$id}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    } elseif (empty($_GET['id'])) {
        header("location: manage_posts.php");
    }
}
?>
<form action="modify_post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
    <h3>Post Title <?php //echo $id; ?></h3>
    <input name="title" value="<?php echo $rows['title'];?>" type="text" placeholder="Title here ..." id="title" required>
    <h3>Post Content</h3>
    <textarea name="content" required  placeholder="Title here ..." style="resize: none"><?php echo $rows['content'];?></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" id="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if ($_POST['title'] != "" || $_POST['content'] != "") {
        $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['id']);
        $sql = "UPDATE posts SET title='{$_POST['title']}', content='{$_POST['content']}' WHERE id='{$id}'";
        $update_result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if (isset($result)) {
            echo "<h2>Update successfully, redirecting back ...</h2>";
        } else {
            echo "Record hasn't been Updated" . mysqli_errno($result);
        }

        header("location: manage_posts.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Please fill all fields</h3>";
    }
}
?>
```

This is all what I could came up with !

I don't know where is the problem coming from ?

Comment: Any error messages? Do title or content contain quotes? You are open to sql injections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: `$update_result = mysqli_... if (isset($result))` - what is $result?

Comment: And `$_GET['id']` is correct?

Comment: Also `if ($_GET) {` seems rather redundant if underneath you are checking if `id` is set.

Comment: Can you describe the current behavior? Do you get `Update successfully, redirecting back .` and it just isnt updated in the DB? Your header won't work because you are outputting content before it.

Comment: I'm having an issue while the string has special chars how can I avoid that ?

Comment: What is the special char? A quote?

Comment: yes ! 
I'll try htmlspecialchars()

Comment: Use prepared statements see link in my first comment, or answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) avoid [sql injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) e.g. with [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) + parameters
b) add more error handling and parameter checking.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    echo 'wrong method';
}
else if ( !isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content']) ) {
    echo 'missing POST parameters';
}
else if ( !isset($_GET['id']) ) {
    echo 'missing GET parameter';
}
else if ($_POST['title'] == "" || $_POST['content'] == "") {
    echo '<h3>Please fill all fields</h3>';
}
else {
    $stmt = $connect->prepare('UPDATE posts SET title=?, content=? WHERE id=?');
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        trigger_error('prepare failed', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else  if ( !$stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_GET['id']) ) {
        trigger_error('bind_param failed', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
        trigger_error('execute failed', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else {  
        echo '# of updated rows: ', $stmt->affected_rows();
    }
}
```

see also

- http://docs.php.net/mysqli.error-list
- http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.error-list

Comment: that's Object Oriented I think 
!

Comment: Yes, it is! So what?

Comment: I'm still new to this language 
Only applying What I've just learned on the procedural php

Comment: `mysqli_prepare($connect, ...)` vs `$connect->prepare()` - not a big deal.

Comment: btw: I didn't take into account that printing the form's code and processing the response happens in the same script, so you probably have to adjust the the first if-condition.

Comment: I really have no Idea about that
I've just started learning php 4 days ago !

Comment: It really doesn't matter in case of using the mysqli extension. You can always switch forth and back between the procedual style (what you're currently using) and the oo style. see http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface